# Angularjs ng-repeat filter with multiselected values from multiselect dropdown

Tags: angularjs

[image]I have bind data to table from Json Object,i need to implement column wise multiselect dropdown filter for the data. i have done the single dropdown selection.filter required on multiple selections on each column dropdown.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: you've listed your requirements, what is the question? where are you stuck?

Comment: Multi select drop-down for each column based on selection table data need to be filter.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand the question but  you can take a look  [Here](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs/#/main) .

it works really nice and it works also on mobile phones .